# multi-threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a code like this in python:

```
c1=threading.Thread(target=GenQueue.producer(users_c1, 1), daemon=True).start()
c2=threading.Thread(target=GenQueue.producer_(users_c2, 2), daemon=True).start()
```

And with this I want to start both process in the same time. In other words, I want to process the two functions on the same time, but running the program I have the following response:

```
c1
2.1834390934945658
c1
0.35337611584765205
c1
0.4002003042210114
c1
0.9425023162426116
c2
1.8306126431113086
c2
2.812330137689151
c2
4.292045901607802
c2
5.073242410662336
c2
1.1971281688107942
c2
1.5540286958713654
c2
0.5082889643899778
```

as you can see the programming is executing all part to function c1 first and when finish, starts to execute the function to c2.

am I doing something wrong?

Thank you everyone

Comment: the target parameter should be a callable object, it looks like you're executing it in the line and passing the return value to the thread

Comment: ate target on my thread is a function thats pertence in a class. Is that wrong?

Comment: What does the "GenQueue.producer" method do and what does it return? It should return a function object or a callable object to make this work.

Comment: class GenQueue:def producer_(users_in_simulation, item_class):
        users_in_simulation = 2
        for users in range(1, users_in_simulation+1):
            #random: BS
            item_bs = random.randint(1,2)
            #define tipe of the class
            #item_class = random.randint(1,3)
            #define sleep time for each class
            if item_class == 1 or item_class == 3: #classe 1
                GenQueue.queue_c1(item_bs)
            elif item_class == 2: #classe 2
                GenQueue.queue_c2(item_bs)

Comment: what I want is simulate the arrival of users in a system. but I have two possibles classes of users, with different time of arrival in system. each thread need to generate an user considering the arrival time that I specified. in this way, the two threads needs to work in the same time, simulating the process of arrival users, do you understand? I'm using threads because I thought is the more easy way to do this... but in my case, is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to use threads:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=client_loop, args=(client, broker_p, port, token, 600, pub))
```

As you can see, the target param is your function (GenQueue.producer) and args is (users_c1, 1), which are the parameters that your target function takes.

So it should look like this:

```
c1=threading.Thread(target=GenQueue.producer, args = (users_c1, 1), daemon=True)
c1.start()
...
...
```